# Paypal third party carts can discount be sent for individual items

Tags: php, magento, paypal, shopping-cart

I have a range of products to send to paypal via a third party cart. I am aware I can set a whole discount for the cart whicg includes every item. But is is possible to set this up for each item or would I have to work out the equations in php and attach the discounted price to the cart data.

I know this works for a whole cart:

> Use discount_amount_cart to charge a single discount amount for the
>   entire cart. Use discount_amount_x to set a discount amount associated
>   with item x. Use discount_rate_cart to charge a single discount
>   percentage for the entire cart. Use discount_rate_x to set a discount
>   percentage associated with item x.

taken form the paypal [developers docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/)

I am curious as to wether soemthing like this would work:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="discount_item_*x*" value="50%">
 <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_item_*x*" value="*product name*">
```

I know this doesn't work as it adds the 50% discount to the whole cart instead of the individual items within the cart as intended.

I had the idea of working out the discount first then sending the new value to paypal

Answer (score 0):

You're close:

```
<input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_*x*" value="50.00">
```

for discount *amounts,* e.g. 50.00 dollars, or for percentages:

```
<input type="hidden" name="discount_rate_*x*" value="10">
```

for 10% discount. Note that you don't send the "%".